# UI Tab Bar added to Storyboard not showing up when I build the App

Tags: ios7, delegates, storyboard, viewcontroller, tabbar

I have an iOS App.  I currently have an existing View Controller.  I manually added a UI Tab Bar to it using the storyboard.
I added the UITabBarDelegate and implemented the corresponding functions required tabBar:tabBar didSelectItem:item.
I've also connected the delegate of the Tab Bar to the view controller itself.

However, when I build, the Tab Bar completely does not show up at all.

I know you can just use a Tab Bar Controller, but I need to add the Tab Bar to it, and use the Tab Bar to modify content of the view itself. (specifically it acts as a filter for a table view) So, it doesnt make sense to create 4 exact same Views to hook up to a UI Tab View Controller

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's wrong.

It turns out, I had completely successfully implemented the UITabBar.  What happened was that I was testing on an IPhone 4.  As such, it bled out of the screen and could not be seen.  Adding constraints fixed it.